# HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath findvalue not working

Tags: html, perl, xpath, xhtml

I'm trying to get the value "Buffalo" from the following HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Scrape Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="holder-305857" class="event-holder holder-scheduled">
    <div id="305857" class="eventLine status-scheduled" rel="2015-01-29 21:30:00" itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsEvent" itemscope="">
      <meta itemprop="startdate" content="2015-01-29T21:30:00-05:00" />
      <meta itemprop="name" content="Buffalo Sabres@Edmonton Oilers" />
      <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nhl-hockey/buffalo-vs-edmonton-305857/" />
      <div class="score-content"></div>

      <div class="el-div eventLine-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxItem" /> <a href="http://www.sportsbookreview.com/nhl-hockey/matchups/20150129-70/" style="display:none">matchuplink</a>
      </div>

      <div class="el-div eventLine-rotation" itemprop="location" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" itemscope="">
        <div class="eventLine-book-value">
          069
        </div>

        <div class="eventLine-book-value">
          070
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="el-div eventLine-time" id="time-305857">
        <div class="eventLine-book-value">
          9:30p
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="el-div eventLine-team">
        <div class="eventLine-value">
          <span class="team-name" rel="583">Buffalo</span>
        </div>

        <div class="eventLine-value">
          <span class="team-name" rel="579">Edmonton</span>
        </div><span class="options"><button class="options-btn"><span class="options">Options</span></button></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Perl to try and extract the text. Specifically, I'm using the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_file('html.html');

my $test_value = $tree->findvalue('//*[@id="305857"]/div[5]/div[1]/span');
print $test_value . "\n";
```

I would expect the printed text to be "Buffalo" but it's not. I'm stumped, can you help? TIA

Comment: Perhaps you should rather use `XML::LibXML->load_html()` ? And then the actual problem is that there is a _default namespace_ in your document.

Comment: I don't use XPath much, but wouldn't it be easier to do something like `//span[@class='team-name'][1]/text()`?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes, that's much better - but it does not solve the problem completely because `span` is still in a namespace and because this will yield _both_ team names. Both `span` elements are the first child of something.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML document is really an XHTML document that has a *default namespace*:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

An XPath expression like `//div` only finds `div` elements if they are in no namespace - your `div` elements *are* in a namespace.

Also, do not make an XPath expression overly complicated, as ThisSuitIsBlackNot suggests, and change it to `//span[@class='team-name']/text()` if the class name can be relied upon.

There are two solutions to your problem: Either you declare this namespace in your Perl code and then *prefix* element names in your XPath expression - or ignore namespaces in the input document.

**Declare the XHTML Namespace**

This option means making the namespace URI "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" available to the XPath environment. I could not find any explanation of how to declare namespaces with `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`. But you could use [`XML::LibXML`](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0117/LibXML.pod) in its stead, and [use `registerNs()` to declare the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28203516/1987598).

**Ignoring Namespaces**

The following XPath expression works regardless of namespaces present in the document:

```
//*[local-name() = 'span' and @class='team-name']/text()
```

Yet, it retrieves two text nodes:

```
Buffalo
-----------------------
Edmonton
```

You can access only "Buffalo" with

```
(//*[local-name() = 'span' and @class='team-name']/text())[1]
```

**EDIT**: Responding to your comment:

> Sorry, I should of been more clear. There are several "team-name" classes in the actual code, so querying against that will not work.

Yes, you should have been more clear. Always make sure the downsized sample you include in a question accurately reflects all the complexity present in your real data.

Then, disregarding namespaces in the expression becomes more cumbersome, but can be done nevertheless:

```
//*[@id="305857"]/*[local-name() = 'div' and position() = 5]/*[local-name() = 'div' and position() = 1]/*[local-name() = 'span']
```

---

**EDIT2**

> the expression you created still doesn't work in my PERL code. The value returned is still empty. Any thoughts?

Yes, there's a bunch of other problems. For example, there simply is nothing on that page with the ID "305857" as far as I can see. Also, the page is invalid XHTML, because the ID values are not unique and there are unescaped "&" in it.

I've now written a complete example with `HTML::TreeBuilder` so nothing can go wrong. Note that `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` seems to simply disregard namespaces (unlike LibXML), so you can use unprefixed element names.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_file('mypage.html');
my $value = $tree->findvalue('//*[@id="holder-305862"]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/span');
print $value;
```

The result, using the whole page at the URL you described, after fixing the HTML to make it valid XHTML:

```
Buffalo
```

Comment: Sorry, I should of been more clear. There are several "team-name" classes in the actual code, so querying against that will not work. Here is the actual live page: http://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nhl-hockey/pointspread/. I am right clicking on the team name in chrome and selecting 'Copy Xpath' to get the path of the text I want to export.

Comment: the expression you created still doesn't work in my PERL code. The value returned is still empty. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Mathias is correct, the problem is that your document does not validate.

Here's a perl script that will work, it uses HTML::Tidy (requires tidyp to be installed) to clean your document before parsing it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Tidy;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $mess;

{
  open(F, "messy.html");
  local $/ = undef;
  $mess = <F>;
}

my $tidy = HTML::Tidy->new();
my $fresh = $tidy->clean($mess);

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($fresh);

my $value = $tree->findvalue('//*[@id="305862"]/div[5]/div[1]/span');
print $value;
```